# Authenticating to Salesforce using OAuth2 in python

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I have just started working in Python and have no experience working with API's.I can make the initial request that causes the browser window to open and user has to enter username and password.After that the user is redirected and the authorization code is returned in the URL.How do i get the code out of the browser and store it?

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
import webbrowser

flow = SalesforceOAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id=SF_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=SF_CLIENT_SECTION,
    scope=['api', 'refresh_token', 'full'] ,
    redirect_uri='http://myexample.com/sfoauth2callback'
)

authorization_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

webbrowser.open(auth_uri)

code=' '

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

Any help or examples of a working code  would be greatly appreciated.I have been stuck on this for a week now.Thanks for your time.

Comment: I could get this example to work on localhost but not on heroku.  What are we doing wrong!?

Comment: I also stuck here (I am using the newer version) but once I approve the page, the python app is stuck, this is happening in localhost :(.